# Highlight a specific DIV depending on URL

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a list of **FAQs** on, say, page `faq.html` like so:

```
<div id="faq1">...</div>
<div id="faq2">...</div>
```

I now want to pulsate or simply highlight one of those `DIVs` when I send a visitor there through a specific URL. Say on my checkout page I have a link saying `"Find help here"` and it's linked to `#faq2`.

How can I trigger a simple highlight animation `(pulsate/blink)` in the background on the `FAQ Div` **element through** adding a trigger in the URL like so:

http://www.test.com/faq.html?highlight=faq2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can ad a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) to the URL you can use the CSS `:target` pseudo-class.

http://jsfiddle.net/9yNVp/

HTML:

```
<a href="#see" id="see">See</a> <a href="#works" id="works">works</a> <a href="#well" id="well">well</a>​
```

CSS:

```
a:target{
    transition:background-color 1s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 1s ease-in;
    -moz-transition:background-color 1s ease-in;
    background-color: yellow;
}​
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you execute that?

Answer (score 0):

for highlighting it you can do this

```
var Blinkcnt = 0;
function BlinkDiv(DivId) {
    if (Blinkcnt % 2 == 0) {
        $('#' + DivId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#E1E1E1" }, 500);
        Blinkcnt += 1;
    }
    else {
        $('#' + DivId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8" }, 500);
        Blinkcnt += 1;
    }
    if (Blinkcnt < 10) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            BlinkDiv();
        }, 500);
    }
    else {
        Blinkcnt = 0;
        $('#' + DivId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#F8F8F8" }, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this using the CSS `:target` selector (so to target `faq2` only when the fragment is `#faq2`, use `faq2:target` `{ ... }` ).

Also to animate it, look into **CSS3 transitions** and keyframes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var params = window.location.href.split('?')[1].trim().split('&');
    var location = '';

    for( var i=0; i<params.length; i++ ) {
        var pair = params[i].split('=');
        location = pair[0] ==='highlight' ? pair[1] : '';
    }

    if ( location ) {
        $('#'+location).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
        // or $('#'+location).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
    }
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate

Comment: Using these jQuery UI effects requires you to include the jQuery UI source