# How do i highlight a specific table row depending on the url

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay lets say i have a table with first names and last names and i want to highlight the whole row depending on the url for example if i had `example.com/test#namex`
it would highlight the whole row of the table

I tried to do this using the css that I found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210195/highlight-a-specific-div-depending-on-url)

```css
a:target {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="namex">
    <td>namex</td>
    <td>namex2</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="namey">
    <td>namey</td>
    <td>namey2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: use only `:target {}` or `tr:target {}`

Answer (score 3):

In CSS you need just :target (tr:target if you only want to highlight the table row and not other things with ID)

```
:target {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

If you want, you can use JavaScript to do it too

Assuming the ID matches the hash, add this to the head of your page

```
<script>
var srch = window.location.search;
document.querySelector(srch).style.background = "yellow";
</script>
```

Working Examples are here - note I had to set the `var srch = "#namex";` in the examples because StackOverflow will have another hash value

```js
var srch = "#namex"; // change to window.location.search;
document.querySelector(srch).style.background = "yellow";
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="namex">
     <td>namex</td>
     <td>namex2</td>
</tr>

<tr id="namey">
     <td>namey</td>
     <td>namey2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Or this

```js
var srch = "#namex"; // change to window.location.search;
document.querySelector(srch).classList.add("highlight")
```

```css
.highlight {
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1s ease-in;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr id="namex">
     <td>namex</td>
     <td>namex2</td>
</tr>

<tr id="namey">
     <td>namey</td>
     <td>namey2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, i did not see IDs. I had saw just `textContent`

Comment: Sorry what language is that in?  Sorry im still kinda new to all this.

Comment: @sionTea Please see my updated answer for how to implement the JavaScript I wrote

Comment: @mplungjan hmm well i didn't get it to work i put that `var srch = "#namex"; // change to window.location.search;
document.querySelector(srch).style.background = "yellow";` in a <script> but yeah it didn't work,  i might have done something wrong

Comment: we don't really need JS. He simply need to read carefully the question he linked ...

Comment: @sionTea - I did not notice the a:  - try just `:target`